# Vim macro not working because of the shortcuts overlapping with Quick Fix command

Tags: vim, vim-macros, vim-quickfix

So, I was trying to write a Vim macro and the macro `@p` I registered below includes a `cc` shortcuts which deletes a line. The macro is as follows.

```
" macro @p
qp
cc{<ESC>j@eA,<ESC>j@ejcc},<ESC>
q
```

When I run the macro `@p` itself, it works just fine.

```
" macro @q
qq
@pj
q
```

However, when I registered another macro `@q` that uses macro `@p`, and try to repeat macro `@q` until the end of file by using `:999@q`, it says

```
E42: No errors: cc
```

and I have no idea why this isn't working.

I realize this has to do with Quick fix command, and found that there is `:cc` command in `quickfix.txt`. I doubt that my problem derives from here.(Because the shortcut for deleting line in Vim is the same as the shortcut for quick fix as `cc`.

Is Quick fix the reason why I get the `E42: No errors: cc`?
How can I fix the problem? Just so you know, I am using MAC OS and neovim.

Answer (score 1):

When you do:

```
:999@q
```

the macro `@q` is expanded, so you are actually doing:

```
:999@pj
```

in which the macro `@p` is also expanded, so you are actually doing:

```
:999cc{<ESC>j@eA,<ESC>j@ejcc},<ESC>j
```

(and then there is the macro `@e` that is missing from your question, so you eventually end up doing something else we can't really know).

At this point it should be obvious that the normal mode `cc` from `@p` is executed as command-line mode `:999cc`, which throws an error because you don't have a quickfix list with at least 999 entries.

The problem is thus that you are executing a *normal mode* macro in *command-line mode*. Doing `999@q` in normal mode (note the missing `:`) should fix your problem.